# QGIS variable cardinal buffering of points

Tags: qgis, buffer

Is there a way of creating a buffer (elliptical I guess) in QGIS that has independent distances to the North, South, East & West (from the attribute table) so the buffer could be 5m wide to the North, 4m to the East, 6m to the South & 2m to the West? This is to show tree crown dimensions on a map.

Comment: Try Rectangles, ovals, diamonds processing tool. At least possible to specify width and height

Answer (score 2):

You can consider to use the geometry generator to do this job for you. The geometry generator will only generate the geometry of your symbol. The example below has a point theme with 4 attributes: "n", "s", "e" and "w" for your values and makes a polygon symbol with this four values with the expression:

```
smooth(
make_rectangle_3points(
make_point($x-"w",$y-"s"),
make_point($x-"w",$y+"n"),
make_point($x+"e",$y+"n")),
3)
```

it takes the pointgeometries ($x and $y) and generates a rectangle with the values from "n", "s", "e" and "w", which will be smoothed afterwards:

[image]